# Constrain type arg based on existing overloads

Tags: c#, .net, generics, constraints, overloading

Let's say Foo has 2 overloads:

```
void Foo(int[] array) { ... }
void Foo(int[,] array) { ... }
```

I've written a function a function Bar, which calls Foo, and I want Bar to support both int[] and int[,] arguments, so I have this:

```
void Bar(int[] array)
{
    // do some work here, and finally call Foo:
    Foo(array);
}

void Bar(int[,] array)
{
    // do some work here, and finally call Foo:
    Foo(array);
}
```

I want to remove the code duplication by making just one, generic Bar method. Pseudocode:

```
void Bar<TArray>(TArray array)
    where TArray is_a_type_accepted_by Foo
{
    // do some work here, and finally call Foo:
    Foo(array);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a constraint is not possible in C#.